# Tooltip not working on submit button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code in my HTML file:

```
<div class="first">
    <label> Enter Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="pword1" class="iBox" id="pword1" onmouseout="HideToolTip()" onmouseover="ShowToolTip()" onkeyup="allFunctions()" placeholder="choose a password" autocomplete="off">
        <p id="tooltipbox" style="visibility:hidden">This is the tooltip</p>
    </div>

    <div class="second">
        <label> Confirm Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="cPassword" class="iBox"  id="cPassword" onkeyup="passwordValidation()" placeholder="confirm it!" autocomplete="off">
        <p id="combination"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="third">
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="submit" disabled="disabled" onmouseout="SubmitToolTipHide()" onmouseover="SubmitToolTip()">
        <p id="subTT" style="visibility:hidden">Passwords do not match</p>
    </div>
```

And these are my functions:

```
function ShowToolTip(){
    document.getElementById("tooltipbox").style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function HideToolTip(){
    document.getElementById("tooltipbox").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function SubmitToolTip(){
    document.getElementById("subTT").style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function SubmitToolTipHide(){
    document.getElementById("subTT").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

When I hover over the textarea for the password the tooltip correctly displays and when I move the mouse outside the region the tooltip correctly disappears.
I cannot understand why, with the same logic, it will not appear over the submit button when I hover over that. Even though I have used the same Javascript function.

Comment: It is because the submit button is disabled.

http://jsfiddle.net/ssbiswal1987/gn0jgj3d/

Comment: Your submit button is disabled. Also, you're missing a </div> in your HTML :) (<div id="first"> is NOT being closed)

Comment: @briosheje is it not being closed on the 4th line?

Comment: Ooh well, it was edited, I had the previous text, the </div> on the 4th line was missing when I copied it, but I didn't notice it had been edited :D. Anyway, just saying, but there are beautiful tooltips that can be integrated using bootstrap, which may be even way more helpful for making responsive web design. Take a look at it, you will surely like it ;) http://getbootstrap.com/ . Aaand the bootstrap tooltips: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your submit button is disabled. If you remove disabled="disabled" it will work. In that code it might make sense to do a check when the password field changes and show/hide the tooltip then, rather than on hover - and just leave the submit button disabled, until they match.